# How to associate a number to a date class in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data frame with a date column like the following:

| Decade |
| --- |
| 1770-1779 |
| 1780-1789 |
| 1770-1779 |
| 1820-1829 |
| 1770-1779 |
| 1790-1799 |
| 1800-1809 |
| 1810-1819 |

etc...

The desired output is to add a continous variable "Time" like this:

| Decade | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 1770-1779 | 1 |
| 1780-1789 | 2 |
| 1770-1779 | 1 |
| 1820-1829 | 6 |
| 1770-1779 | 1 |
| 1790-1799 | 3 |
| 1800-1809 | 4 |
| 1810-1819 | 5 |

etc...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `base R` with `factor`

```
df$Time <- as.integer(factor(df$Decade, levels = sort(unique(df$Decade))))
```

-output

```
> df
     Decade Time
1 1770-1779    1
2 1780-1789    2
3 1770-1779    1
4 1820-1829    6
5 1770-1779    1
6 1790-1799    3
7 1800-1809    4
8 1810-1819    5
```

---

Or another option is `match`

```
with(df, match(Decade, sort(unique(Decade))))
[1] 1 2 1 6 1 3 4 5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Decade = c("1770-1779", "1780-1789", "1770-1779", 
"1820-1829", "1770-1779", "1790-1799", "1800-1809", "1810-1819"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 2):

The function you need is `cur_group_id()` from the package `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Decade) %>% mutate(Time = cur_group_id())

# A tibble: 8 × 2
# Groups:   Decade [6]
  Decade     Time
  <chr>     <int>
1 1770-1779     1
2 1780-1789     2
3 1770-1779     1
4 1820-1829     6
5 1770-1779     1
6 1790-1799     3
7 1800-1809     4
8 1810-1819     5
```

#### Data

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "
Decade
1770-1779
1780-1789
1770-1779
1820-1829
1770-1779
1790-1799
1800-1809
1810-1819")
```